# Split Double Value from textbox into multiple array

Tags: c#, winforms, split

can someone show me how i can split value of double like this:-

```
654782.690
```

Can i split the value into this =

```
int i[0] = 65
int i[1] =  4
int i[2] =  7
int i[3] =  8
double i[4] = 2.690
```

Appreciate for the answer. Thank you in advance.

EDITED***

I have the UTM coordinate value in my xml. I want to make the chart and the value for the coordinate is fall into the grid. Lets say i have the zone area of x1 (578462.254), y1 (648523.124) & x2 (578481.452), y2 (648474.156). In my xml, i have a datapoint which fall under this coordinate. What i would like to do is to make the chart grid with the first two digit is become the zone area min and max(x,y).

I hope my clarification can explain what i want to do with those data.  Thank you very much.

I got the answer here:-

```
decimal dValue = 654782.690;
string sValue = dValue.ToString();

decimal[] dArray = new decimal[5];
dArray[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(0, 2));
dArray[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(2, 1));
dArray[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(3, 1));
dArray[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(4, 1));
dArray[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(5));
```

Its worked now!!! Thank you for your support to solve my problem. :)

Comment: Why first element is containing 2 digit. and why last digit with decimal are not stored in `double` array instead? BTW, either u can create array for int or double.

Comment: It's not splitting, it's substring.

Comment: It is better to ask what you want to do instead of how you want to do? so users can give proper suggestion if you are wrong anywhere.

Comment: why the 0 indexed element is having two digits

Comment: hi, the first element is to bind the value into chart grid.

Comment: `654782.690` is the fixed range value. I mean every value will have decimal value like `(6d.3d)`?

Comment: i think you need to convert each input number into three parts ,frst part contains 2digit, second is a array , third is a value like x.xxxx, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decimal` instead of `double` if you are not storing scientific value.

```
decimal dValue = 654782.690M;
string sValue = dValue.ToString();

deciaml[] dArray = new  decimal[5];
dArray[0] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(0,2));
dArray[1] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(2,1));
dArray[2] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(3,1));
dArray[3] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(4,1));
dArray[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(sValue.Substring(5));
```

To use the value of array index of 0 to 3 use `Convert.ToInt32()` to convert in Int datatype.

```
int iValue  = Convert.ToInt32(dArray[0]);
```

*Above example is not compiled it may give error. Take this example as a logic.*

Comment: It's worked. Thanks for your help Shell. I really appreciated your answer.